# Filter Values of Current Week with XQuery

Tags: xquery

I am extracting data from Sharepoint using XQuery. The xquery code is:

```
{for $ancestor0 in $queryresponse//*:row
return<Row>
<Title>{fn:data($ancestor0/@ows_Title)}</Title>
<EventDate>{fn:data($ancestor0/@ows_EventDate)}</EventDate>
```

The data returned is:

```
<h1>Meeting Agenda  Event Date</h1>
New England APCD Work Group 6/26/2013  
NY APD Workgroup    6/27/2013  
MCDB 2012 Data Submission Bi-weekly 7/2/2013  
MA APCD 7/3/2013  
VA APCD Monthly Status  7/4/2013  
Cross State Meeting 7/5/2013  
NY APD Workgroup    7/11/2013  
MA APCD 7/17/2013  
Cross State Meeting 7/19/2013  
NY APD Workgroup    7/25/2013  
MA APCD 7/31/2013  
New England APCD Work Group 7/31/2013  
VA APCD Monthly Status  8/1/2013  
Cross State Meeting 8/2/2013
```

I need to get the rows that are in the current-week? so I would the get only the following rows as results:

```
MA APCD 7/17/2013  
Cross State Meeting 7/19/2013
```

Can someone help me on the code?

Answer (score 1):

In the end you need to solve two problems. One is parsing these dates, the other verifying if they're in the current week.

### Testing if Dates are in Same Week

Testing whether a day is in the current week is only a special case of whether a day is in the same week of a given day, namely the current day one's.

```
declare function local:in-current-week($date as xs:date)
as xs:boolean
{
  local:in-same-week(current-date(), $date)
};
```

For testing whether a day is in a given week, you need to find start and end of week. Finding the start of week is easy if you know the day of week; and finding this can be done by counting the days from a known start of week (choose arbitrarily, lets go for Sunday June 23rd, 1912) and use the remainder of dividing by a week's length.

If you want weeks to start at a Monday, just change the date to one, I'd go for January 10th, 1938.

```
declare function local:in-same-week($date1 as xs:date, $date2 as xs:date)
as xs:boolean
{

  let $dayOfMonth := abs(($date1 - xs:date('1912-06-23')) div xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D') mod 7)
  let $startOfWeek := $date1 - $dayOfMonth * xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')
  let $endOfWeek := $startOfWeek + 7 * xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')
  return $startOfWeek <= $date2 and $date2 < $endOfWeek
};

local:in-current-week(xs:date('2013-07-17'))
```

### Constructing an `xs:date` From US Date Format

This does not involve anything more than a simple regular expression (valid for all dates AC.):

```
xs:date(replace('07/10/2013', '(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d+)', '$3-$1-$2'))
```

---

Finally you can filter by adding this `where` clause to your query:

```
where local:in-current-week(xs:date(replace(@ows_Title, '(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})', '$3-$1-$2')))
```