# xquery- filtering with dynamic date

Tags: xquery

I have the following code:

```
<Table><ColumnHeaders>
<ColumnHeader  name='Title' type='xs:string' />
<ColumnHeader  name='EventDate' type='xs:date' />
<ColumnHeader  name='today' type='xs:date' />
<ColumnHeader  name='day-week' type='xs:integer' />
<ColumnHeader  name='dur-end' type='xs:integer' />
<ColumnHeader  name='start-date' type='xs:date' />
<ColumnHeader  name='end-date' type='xs:date' />
</ColumnHeaders>
<Data>{let $today := fn:current-date()
let $day-week := functx:day-of-week($today)
let $dur-end := 6-$day-week
let $start-date := xs:date($today)-(xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')*$day-week)
let $end-date := xs:date($today)+(xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')*$dur-end)
for $ancestor0 in $queryresponse//*:row
where ($ancestor0/@ows_EventDate)>=$start-date
return<Row>
<Title>{fn:data($ancestor0/@ows_Title)}</Title>
<EventDate>{fn:data($ancestor0/@ows_EventDate)}</EventDate>
<today>{fn:data($today)}</today>
<day-week>{fn:data($day-week)}</day-week>
<dur-end>{fn:data($dur-end)}</dur-end>
<start-date>{fn:data($start-date)}</start-date>
<end-date>{fn:data($end-date)}</end-date>
</Row>}
</Data></Table>
```

after adding the where clause in the "for statement", the xquery failed with the following error:

**ZorbaDynamicException failed. Zorba engine encountered a dynamic error. 
Error type: XQuery Engine error. Passed item (of type UNTYPED_ATOMIC) is not castable to passed target type (xs:date).**

can someone please help me in fixing this issue?

Comment: I already described that in [an answer to your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17738471/xquery-to-get-the-date-values-in-current-week): The date representation you have is not compatible to XQuery dates, so you have to convert it.

Comment: Hi,
I am a newbie to Xquery, actually I didn’t understand your answer to my original post and I felt uncomfortable in asking you to explain it in detail. That’s why I tried my own logic, but unfortunately it didn’t work too. If in case you have some time, can you please try explaining it a bit detail?
Also, if there is any xquery book that you would recommend for a beginner that would be great.
Regards,

Comment: Which parts didn't you understand? I admit that learning XQuery isn't to easy in the beginning if you are not used to declarative languages. Can't help you with a proposal for a book, I learned it in an university lecture. The current problem is that your date format is no standard ISO date format and thus needs to be aligned which I solved in my answer using a regular expression.

Comment: A really good book to learn XQuery is ["XQuery" by Priscilla Walmsley](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596006341.do).

Answer (score 0):

The value resulting from $ancestor0/@ows_EventDate is not castable to a date. You can use the parse-date function contained in Zorba's datetime module (http://www.zorba.io/documentation/2.9/modules/www.zorba-xquery.com_modules_datetime.html) to convert the string into a date.

For example,

```
d:parse-date($ancestor0/@/@ows_EventDate/text(), "%D")
```

if your date is formatted as MM/DD/YY.